# How to go to the next row by using index to iterate through the dataframe?

Tags: pandas

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJjEl.png)I am using index to iterate through the dataframe. I want to get close column of the current row and the next row to do some calculation. I am able to pick the current row closing price but not able to do it for the next row.

`for z in bn:
      bn["Date"][z+1]`

it is giving me a key error.

Kindly suggest

Comment: Would [`Series.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) help here? Generally if you're iterating using pandas, then you're probably "not doing it right" :)

Comment: What kind of error? Could you elaborate a little bit more?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like, you're looking for [pd.DataFrame.shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html#pandas-dataframe-shift), that moves selected column n rows up or down.

In case you want to access rows by index, use [pd.DataFrame.iloc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html#pandas-dataframe-iloc). In you example:

```
bn["Date"].iloc[z+1]
```